# color text using StyleFrame in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, formatting, styleframe

I want to have a yellow background in some certain rows and in those rows I want some text to be red. Here is an example :

[image]

So far I am able to achieve yellow background in some certain rows using :

```
 from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler

 bgStyle = Styler(bg_color='yellow')
 sf = StyleFrame(df)
 sf.apply_style_by_indexes(rowsTocolor, styler_obj=bgStyle, overwrite_default_style=False)
```

But I cant find a way to color a particular text red in that yellow background row.

So my question is, is it possible to achieve this using `StyleFrame`? If yes, then how? if not, then which other library should i use?

Comment: Do you mean that you want cell B1 to contain 'b 35 45 68', and only '45' should be red?

Comment: yes. But this is just an example. Basically, I want to color string of a cell partially.

Comment: I've done some digging around and it does not look like openpyxl (which styleframe uses) supports that

Comment: After my research till now, i also didn't find any library which supports that.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that it is not possible to do?